# Distance and speed question on minimum time

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle, quadratics, word-problem

Suppose that there is a narrow bridge 4 metres wide that only 1 bus can pass on it. The bus is travelling at 10m/s and it is moving with constant speed. A man is 2m away from the bus and is crossing the bridge in a hurry. If the man is walking at 1.5m/s, what will be the minimum time taken.

This is an image of the problem:

[image]

Let the point at which man is standing be B. Now,

$d_{man} = AB = \sqrt{x^2 + 16}$

$d_{bus} = 2+x$

$t_{man} = t_{bus}$ (as time taken by bus to reach B should be equal to time taken by man to reach B, for least time.)

$$\implies \dfrac{x + 2}{10} = \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2 +16}}{1.5}$$

$$\implies 391x^2 - 36x + 6364 = 0$$

This is giving complex roots! Where am i going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think you're doing something wrong? The man *doesn't* have time to cross the road before the bus mows him down -- after just one second the bus will be 8 m to the *right* of his starting position, whereas he can't possibly have reached the other side yet, nor outrun the bus.

He should walk backwards along the sidewalk until the bus has passed, and *then* cross the street perpendicularly.

Comment: I too thought that! 2metres separation is very small! Crossing after the bus has passed is what any sane person would do in this case!